# Using Microsoft Sharepoint List as DataSource in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a problem connecting the SSRS to Sharepoint Online List. I can connect it through Microsoft Excel  (asking for credentials, auth) and can read from the list but when I use the same URL to SSRS it doesnt work and message appears saying that "E_ACCESSDENIED".
[image]
[image]
I search over the internet a lots of threads but without success. I tried all of the auth methods but without success. My thoughts are that my connection string in the SSRS should be different. I really done know and need your help! Thanks!

Here is the error:

```
===================================

Server was unable to process request. ---> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
 (Microsoft Visual Studio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.ExecuteServiceRequest(ServiceRequest request)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.GetLists()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.SharePoint.SharePointTables.Refresh()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.SharePoint.QueryDesigner.Presenter.ValidateConnection()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.SharePoint.SharePointQueryDesigner.InitializeQueryDesigner()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.InternalQueryDesignerWrapper.InitializeDesigner()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.InternalQueryDesignerWithGenericModeWrapper.Initialize()

===================================

Server was unable to process request. ---> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) (System.Web.Services)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPListService.GetListCollection()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetLists>b__0(SPListService listSvc)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.ExecuteServiceRequest(ServiceRequest request)
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that option is only for on-premises versions, not for SharePoint Online. I do not believe you can directly connect SharePoint Online to SSRS.

We set up an SSIS package that pulls list data from SharePoint online into our on-premises database, and then query that within the SSRS report. It works pretty well for our needs.

Comment: I tried and installed the Sharepoint SDK, after that I had error about wrong assembly in the connection and already fixed it. But still Im not able to connect to my Sharepoint Online with MFA. Any tips?

Comment: Test connection failed -> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: I still think you cannot connect SSRS to SharePoint Online (as opposed to an on-premises SharePoint farm) but I did find an article that mentions using this as a connection string: `Data Source=https://MySharePointWeb/MySharePointSite/`. Give that a try and see if it helps. The fact that there is an E_ACCESSDENIED error leads me to believe the connection string is okay, so this may not work.

Comment: Something else to check. I am guessing since you are using SharePoint Online, that you have Azure Active Directory (AAD) set up and are syncing your AD credentials from your local domain to Azure. If that is the case (and it needs to be), the setting under "Use this user name and password" should work as long as the AAD account has access to the list in question. If the AAD account does not have access to the list, it should be given.